# Trying to use display:none on eliminating a couple of H2 elements from an accordion-style element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, accordion

I’ve spent most of the day trying to create a responsive style accordion elements from a WordPress based accordion-style plugin. For the most part….success!

But not completely. The way the plugin works its displays all my categories from my menu, but I don’t want them all displayed. I want a couple eliminated and I’ve tried numerous attempts to do it but to no avail.

The menu doesn’t use ul li elements to produce the code. It uses div’s and h2 elements to produce it. And in my case, the h2’s control the navigation on the left. Like this:

```
<h2 class='fp_menu_sub_section tint_menu 16 collapsable'  data-name='Red Wine' data-src=''>Red Wine<span class='fp_menu_expand'></span></h2>
```

That’s one of the h2’s I’m trying to turn off. So I’ve tried a few approaches. Like the following:

```
body.page-id-354 .fp_menu_sub_section .16 {display: none !important;}
body.page-id-354 .fp_menu_sub_section.tint_menu.16 {display: none !important;}
body.page-id-354 .foodpress_menu h2:nth-child(15) {display: none !important;}
```

These don’t work.

Now this will turn all the navigation off:

```
body.page-id-354 .fp_menu_sub_section {display: none !important;}
```

I just need to turn off a couple of them. Not every one.

Here’s the page in question: http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~panch2/collapisble-menu/

Anyone have a solution how I can do this and make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `body.page-id-354 .fp_menu_sub_section.tint_menu.16 {display: none !important;}` should work no space!

Answer (score 0):

There's no space in an `!important` declaration.  That's the issue here, as each one of those will return as an invalid property.

Comment: That's how it output in Firebug. I didn't add a space and if I tighten it up, it doesn't change anything. Problem still persists.